# 1000000000 * 3 = -1294967296?

Tags: c#, integer-overflow

I'm confused!

Today is November 3rd

```
DateTime DateTime = new DateTime(2010,11,3);
long shazbot = 1000000000 * DateTime.Day;
```

shazbot comes out to -1294967296

Huh???

Comment: I have never used C# but it looks like your long is 32 bits. Signed. huh.

Comment: @Josh, in C# `longs` are [64-bit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctetwysk%28VS.71%29.aspx) wide.

Comment: Try to multiply other pair of System::Int32 and System::Int64 . I'm not C# dev, just interested.

Comment: @foret: Multiplying two different numeric types will cause an [implicit conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx) for the smaller type to the larger.  `System.Int32` * `System.Int64` gives you a `System.Int64` back.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`shazbot` may be a `long`, but neither `1000000000` or `DateTime.Day` are.  So, C# does `int` multiplication first (which results in an overflow) then casts it to a `long` to store in `shazbot`.

If you want a `long` result, make one of them a `long`, like this:

`long shazbot = 1000000000L * DateTime.Day;`

Edit: C# gives you a warning if you use `l` instead of `L`.  Fixed.

Comment: How do I convert my values to long? Convert.ToInt64?

Comment: Alternatively, yes, use a cast like Alexander suggested.  It's just easier if you're using literals to use the type suffix.

Comment: Good catch.. wonder in what framework .NET will do that by itself. :)

Comment: @Soo, "l" is not a trick, it's what tells the compiler what the number is. Similar to "d" for double, "f" for float, "m" for decimal. Otherwise, if you provide an integer literal, the compiler will infer it as an integer, and all decimal literals will be inferred as double. Although if you are going to use the character, the suggestion is to use uppercase L since l is easily confused for 1.

Comment: @RobertPitt: I noticed that... it's strange how the (relatively) simple answers tend to get tons of upvotes fairly quickly, but the ones I take a long time to research and write don't. :|

Comment: @Anthony: Actually, I noticed when I tried it (to make sure `l` really was `long`, I use Java more at work than C# now) that the VS C# compiler spits out a warning if you use `l`, so I updated the original post to use `L` and left an edit note about it.

Comment: @R. Bemrose. It's because everybody can spot a good answer right away when it's simple question :) so, we see the easy question, enter to answer it, see the earliest answer, and instead of writing the same answer again, we upvote.

Comment: @Alexander: There's just a certain form of irony that I'm a 20k+ user and this is now my second-highest voted answer.

Comment: By the way this is similar in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Cast to long like this:

```
long shazbot = 1000000000L * DateTime.Day;
```

Comment: It's enough to cast one of them to `long` to get the expression to evaluate as long.

Comment: Too much to write. There is absolutely no need to cast both operands. One is sufficient. The second will be implicitly cast into the right type. Or, like R. Bemrose suggested, to write a Long literal instead of the default int literal, so that no cast would be needed in this case.

Comment: Thanks I'll change my example.